# MySQL : graph tool to show variables

Tags: mysql, graph, profiling

i need to graph ( with gnuplot or other tools), some variables on a machine running MySql engine . I'm interested on a slow queries vs time, and CPU usage

Have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but **mysql monitor** is what You can look at

Answer (score 0):

You should try **MONyog**-MySQL MOnitor and Advisor from webyog. It has all things what you have mentioned. A typical Real-Time view looks like this.[image]